# Word Math area \funcapply macro strips formatting from contained text after reload

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I use Word's math area to write down Algebra notes, and often use the `\funcapply` macro to denote functions such as `dim`, `ker`, `span` and `Im` which should be displayed upright.

This mostly works as advertised; however, the operand of the `\funcapply` macro (the one appearing to the right of it) loses all formatting after save and load.

```
dim\funcapply (ker\funcapply (T) ) 
span\funcapply \Lambda
```

The image example shows how this looks before save on the left side, and how it looks after the document is reopened on the right side:
[image]
Is there anybody else who encountered this, and if so, how did you solve this?

Comment: I don’t use or understand Word Math formatting, so I (probably) won’t be able to help you.  But can you explain why your first line says ```\funcapply``` twice when only one token changes formatting between left and right?

Comment: `\funcapply` is actually an infix binary operator. when I write `dim\funcapply foo` it does two things: 1) format the word "dim" to appear upright 2) attach "foo" to the "dim" operator as an operand.


I use `\funcapply` twice to denote that `dim` is a *function* accepting `ker(T)` as an argument, and that `ker` is a *function* accepting `T` as an argument.

Comment: Interesting.  The question says, “the inside of the `\funcapply` parameter loses any formatting after save and load,” and it seems like that means, “the *right* side of the `\funcapply` *operator* loses any formatting …,” and I would not have realized that if it weren’t for your comment. I don’t know whether that clarification will be helpful to anybody, but you might want to consider adding it to the question (click on [edit]).